# When a file is transferred form an edge node to a data node what protocol is followed

Tags: hdfs, protocols

I want to know what protocols are used by the following.
edge node to communicate to data node

Edge node to communicate to name node

Name node to communicate to data node

Guess is tcp/ip and RPC

Answer (score 0):

Well after  hours of RND I found this link .. those who are looking  for answers please visit the link below

http://itm-vm.shidler.hawaii.edu/HDFS/ArchDocCommunication.html

Happy learning !